# how to hide one div and display another on button click event in MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Here is my jquery and div i want to hide tblMain and make tblmainalt visible

```js
$("btnUpdate").click(function() {
  alert("button");
  $("tblMain").hide();
  $("tblMainAlt").show();
});
```

```html
<div id="tblMainAlt" class="tableSpaced" style="width:auto;height:100%;margin-left:25px;">
<div id="tblMain" class="tableSpaced" style="width:auto;height:100%;margin-left:25px;">
```

Comment: your selectors are wrong - where are the dots (for classes) or hashes (for ids)?

Comment: Use like this `$("#btnUpdate"), $("#tblMain").hide(); $("#tblMainAlt").show();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because you have used wrong selector. Either you have to use `ID` or `CLASS` selector. As seeing you HTML you please replace your **jQuery** with mine and it will worked.

```
$("#btnUpdate").click(function() {
  alert("button"); // Remove this line if it worked
  $("#tblMain").hide();
  $("#tblMainAlt").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

set display: none in style in tblMainAlt because loaded first time a page so hide a div.

i have add sample code so you can try it.

**JQuery:-**

```
$("#btnUpdate").click(function () {
                alert("button");
                $("#tblMain").hide();
                $("#tblMainAlt").show();
            });

 <div id="tblMainAlt" class="tableSpaced" style="width:auto;height:100%;margin-left:25px;display: none;">

<div id="tblMain" class="tableSpaced" style="width:auto;height:100%;margin-left:25px;">
```

Comment: y shld i chng button id?

Comment: tblMain and tblMainAlt not a tag this is a id so add "#" on below(ID Name) for example "#tblMain" and "#tblMainAlt".

Comment: Any reason for negative voting?

Comment: can anyone tell me how to  access div id into action in controller?

Comment: why access in controller?

Comment: it worked but it shows tblMAinAlt div and it gets hide and shows tblMain div again

Comment: so remove "display: none;" attribute in  tblMainAlt div and modify JS code $("#tblMainAlt").hide(); and  $("#tblMain").show();

Comment: when i click on button then tbkMain shld hide and tblMainAlt Displayed

Comment: i am not getting properly i think  your requirement is tblMain hide and tblMainAlt show on click button right?

Comment: so below code working fine just small changes remove "display: none;" attribute on style in tblMainAlt. any other issues so please tell me.